# cannot load nokogiri gem issue on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

i am beginner with ruby on rails and i have also created a an app but now i want to go for one more app and when i did rails new blog -T then it worked and my app is generated. next i did was rails s and i was shot with an error. and this is an error.

```
  4: from /home/prashant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/loofah-2.2.3/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<main>'
  3: from /home/prashant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
  2: from /home/prashant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
  1: from /home/prashant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
```

/home/prashant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError).

I have done every possible thing that came up with google search but still nothing helps.
these are my versions gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'  ruby '2.5.3'
any help could be greatly appreciated. tired of this nokogiri thing.and on my previous app it never asked me anything like this.
i have also deleted and re created my app for almost 10 to 15 times but still the same error. this error gets shot when i create an app and the very next moment when i starts rails server.. this pops up. rather than rails homepage

Comment: Did You run bundler? Maybe gem install nokogiri?

Comment: hi.. yes i did gem install nokogiri but it did not help.. then i tried to put gem in my gem file gem 'nokogiri' and ran bundle install.. even that did not help..